# Show events AND pageviews in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Each page on my site contains a file, and I have Google Analytics set up to track file download events. I would like to see what fraction of users who visit Page X download Page X's file.

I can view number of events by page by clicking on `Content » Events » Pages`.

**But I can't figure out how to see both events and pageviews (or visits) at the same time.** Visits and pageviews are not available in the `Secondary dimension` dropdown from the Events list, and Events are not available as a `Secondary dimension` in the regular traffic listing (`Content » Site Content » All Pages`).

I want something like this:

```
   Page                         Pageviews     Events
1. /section/mypage                  1,000        123
2. /category/anotherpage              867         41
3. /about/download                     88          7
```

Is there a way to get this in Google Analytics?—to view events and pageviews, by page, at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you've received an answer to this or not, but just in-case.

You want to create a Custom Report and do the following:

In the Metric Groups you want two different metrics:

Total Events and Pageviews

In the Dimension Drilldowns you want to select "Page".

And hopefully that should give you what you want.

Comment: When I do that, the accurate number of events is listed, but page views (and every other traffic metric, like time on page, bounce rate, etc.) are listed as 0.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot

Comment: This gets me very close, but `Total Events` is not a useful metric in my case - I need to note `Page Views` on the `Page` dimension, then drill down to `Event Action` to get the relevant event, then manually calculate a ratio between the two. Very helpful, tx!

Answer (score 1):

In your Google Analytics dashboard click on `Content` then `Events` then `Top Events` then in the top left corner of the report you'll see `Total Events vs Select Metric` click on Select Metric and you can choose `Site Usage` then `Pages / Visit`

Now below near your grid you'll also click `Secondary Dimension` and click on `Content` then `Page` this will show your the page path like you want and events per page path. In the chart you'll have visits vs events.

To get Pageviews into the grid you'll have to create a custom report but the above two settings will give you most of the data you asked for.

Comment: @supertrue, try this out.

Answer (score 1):

@etakt's answer was helpful, but thought I'd document my variation.

I'm trying to answer 'how many visitors to the homepage click the "Load More" button?'.

`Total Events` is not a useful metric in my case, because numerous events occur on each `Page View`.

I need to note `Page Views` on the Page dimension, then drill down to `Event Action` to get the relevant event, then manually calculate a ratio between the two.

```
"Load More" events / Page Views * 100
```

> About ~29% of homepage visitors click the Load More button

Suggest drawing the data into Google Sheets or Data Studio if you want to avoid the manual calculation.

---

Config:

- Metric Group 1

  - `Page Views`
  - `Total Events`
- Dimension Drilldowns

  - `Page`
  - `Event Action`
- Filter

  - Include `Page` exact "/"

---

[image: custom report configuration]